# Making a button display text in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, function, button, onclick

I'm trying to display a number (1, 2, or 3) in my html file when I click a button.

Here is what I have so far:

```
<tr>
    <td><button onclick="setDay(1)">1</button></td>
    <td><button onclick="setDay(2)">2</button></td>
    <td><button onclick="setDay(3)">3</button></td>
</tr>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function setDay(a) {
        var day = a
    }
    document.write(day)
</script>
```

I want to have it so when I click "button '1' ", for example, the function setDay() runs, with my argument set to 1. This way, the variable "day" is set to 1, and then when the variable 'day' is printed the number 1 is displayed. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: document.write will completely overwrite your document, you will not be able to click more then one time,

Comment: Also `var day` will make the variable scoped to that function, it is not visible/usable outside it and since the `write` call is outside the function call it won't update each button click. Use `innerText`,`innerHTML`, or `textContent` of the element you want to change instead of document.write

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple things wrong with your code:

1. You are declaring the day variable inside your function, so whenever the function completes, the variable will be destroyed. So to persist it, move it outside the function and set it from inside.
2. `document.write` will clear your document and replace it with whatever you specify. Hence you need to have another element on which you can display the day.

The code should be:

```js
 var day;    
    function setDay(a) {
      day = a;        
      document.getElementById('day').innerHTML = day;
    }
```

```html
  <tr>
        <td><button onclick="setDay(1)">1</button></td>
        <td><button onclick="setDay(2)">2</button></td>
        <td><button onclick="setDay(3)">3</button></td>
    </tr>
    
    Day : <p id='day'></p>
```

The `document.getElementById('day')` gets the element where you want to display your day, a paragraph tag here, and sets its `innerHTML` or the html inside the element to be the specified day.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear whether you want the 1,2,3 to appear on the buttons when clicked or in a new spot.  either way you want to pass the event and the number to your function.  Then set innerHTML of the element you want the number to appear in.

```js
function setDay(event,a) {
        e=event.target;
        e.innerHTML = a;
        var div = document.getElementById('here');
        var text = div.innerHTML;
        div.innerHTML = text + " " + a;
    }
```

```css
button{
height:36px;
width:36px;
vertical-align:top;
}
```

```html
<tr>
    <td><button onclick="setDay(event,1)"></button></td>
    <td><button onclick="setDay(event,2)"></button></td>
    <td><button onclick="setDay(event,3)"></button></td>
</tr>

<div id="here"></div>
```